# How to access get variable in POCO

Tags: c++, boost, poco

I have created one sample HTTP Server using POCO C++ libarary

http://xjia.heroku.com/2011/09/11/learning-poco-a-simple-http-server/

But i am not able to understand how to read get and post variables.

Does any one have any examples related to this library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `HTTPRequest` and `HTTPResponse` derive from `HTTPMessage`, which has methods like `get`, `has` and `hasToken`.

Also, see the comment by naab and/or try constructing `HTMLForm` from the request stream:

```
HTMLForm(
    const HTTPRequest & request,
    std::istream & requestBody
);
```

Comment: This is for the GET. for the POST one have to read the stream from `HTTPRequest` : `std::istream& istr = request.stream();`

Comment: Thanks. Also, I think you can use HTMLForm